# Python update inherited dictionary

Tags: python, class

I have class

```
class Base:
     filters = {
        'today': '__today'        
    }
```

and another class

```
class Filter(Base):
     new_filters = {
            'yesterday': '__yesterday'        
        }
     filters = {**self.filter, **new_filter}
```

You may see the `filter` class above, I tried to add an additional key but it doesn't seem to work,

Can anyone tell me what is the best way to do it?

Comment: `self` isn't a keyword in Python. The `filters` you're looking for don't belong to any instance; they belong to the `Base` *class, itself*. So that is where you have to look: `Base.filters`. Anyway, please only tag your question according to things that are relevant to *the problem you are asking about*, not just the stuff that your project happens to be using (like Django, in this case).

Comment: There will be one dictionary `filters` that will be shared by all instances of the class `Filter`, is this really what you want? I.e. you cannot create different Filter objects with different filters in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with the `filters` specified in `Base` with `Base.filters`:

```
class Filter(Base):
    new_filters = {
        'yesterday': '__yesterday'
    }
    filters = {**Base.filters, **new_filters}
```